# What are the properties of a function with multiple fixed points?

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, metric-spaces, lipschitz-functions

Let's say that we have a metric space $(M,d)$. Let's denote two subsets of $M$; $A$ and $B$ where $A \cap B=\emptyset$.

Essentially we divide our metric space into two non intersecting chunks. Now let's say that we have a function $f:M \rightarrow M$. The function $f$ has two fixed points that we will denote $a^\star$ and $b^\star$. Given any point in $A$ a repeated application of $f$ on the respective point would converge to $a^\star$. And the same thing with subset and point from $B$.

Another way to state this is that $f$ has a Lipschitz constant of less than 1 (contraction map), for any two points in A, and for any two points in B.

$$\forall a_1,a_2 \in A,d(f(a_1),f(a_2))\leq Ld(a_1,a_2) : L <1$$
$$\forall b_1,b_2 \in B,d(f(b_1),f(b_2))\leq Ld(b_1,b_2) : L <1$$

For this type of function to exist does $f$ have to be expansive ($L$ > 1) for any a point in $A$ and a point in $B$?

Can we state any other properties about $f$?

Comment: @RobertIsrael Yes. Sorry. Fixed the question.

Comment: That's not "another way to state this".  Contraction maps have unique fixed points that are globally attractive, but not all maps that have globally attractive fixed points are contractions.

Answer (score 1):

An example that might be helpful: $A = [-2,-1]$, $B = [1,2]$, with the usual metric of $\mathbb R$.
$$ f(x) = \cases{ \frac{1+x}{2} &  $x \ge 1$\cr
                       \frac{-1+x}{2} &  $x \le -1$\cr} $$

Note that $d(f(x),f(y)) \le d(x,y)$ for all $x, y$.  Of course equality holds in the case $x = a^* = -1, y=b^*=1$.

Comment: I see. In this case $f$ is 1-Lipshitz (non-expansive).